# HTML H1,2,3,4,5,6 Heading Tabs - Still use them

Tags: css, tags, html

I was told while ago that there is no point in using the clasic H1 to H6 heading tags anymore:

```
eg: 
<h1>
<h2>
<h3>
etc
```

The reasons were google doesn't really value them anymore and most often the actual tag choice is altered by CSS so a H6 can look like a H1 (size wise etc).

I was also told that it was better to use span's with CSS.

Can someone shed some light on this - would just like to code in the preferred current direction.

thankyou

Comment: The point to `<h#>` elements is and has always been for semantic page structure.

Comment: It's total bullshit. Who told you that? It doesn't matter how you style them in terms of font-size, the semantic meaning of an h1 still means that it's the most important title on the page.

Comment: thx guys - I'm just learning... its great to have a place like this to get clarity :) thankyou so much

Comment: When in doubt, ask the W3C:  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements.  SEO isn't the only reason to care about the semantic meaning of tags.  Assistive devices (screen readers) rely on them, too.

Comment: We could all learn something if you described who told you that and where. If it was just oral communication, it is best ignored. If there is a written record, online or in print, please cite it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the contrary: there is more reason to use heading tags than ever before. As [the HTML5 draft spec says](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#heading-content)

> Heading content defines the header of a section

Heading elements (`h1`, `h2` and the rest) have a semantic meaning. That is to say, they describe the document in meaningful terms, rather than just in stylistic terms. HTML5 embodies a great leap forward in terms of semantic markup, with elements such as `section`, `article` and `nav` being introduced. These elements allow you to more cogently describe what various parts of your page mean. This allows your HTML and CSS to be more logical. In turn this makes life easier for screen-readers, and for you as a developer.

The heading tags, even though they are old in internet terms, are an indispensable part of this. Use them!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK introducing HTML5, (**in the means of SEO**) the new tags and all, Yes, Google likes to know what's your main title `h1`, what's your article title `h2`, subsection title `h3`, comment title `h4` and everything, for still a `<mainheading>` tag does not exists :)

Now, if you'll make your `H6` huge and your `h1` be `font-size: 1px;` it's up to you as web designer (and SEO follower).